# How to test if an element resides in an iFrame using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to test if an element resides in an iFrame using jQuery and if it does, how to select that iFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it will work for you.

```
var requiredIframe;
$("iframe").each(function(){
  if($(this).contents().find("elementYouAreLookingFor").length){
     requiredIframe = $(this);
     return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know the iframe. What if it doesn't have an id? Start with the element and see if resides in an iFrame.

Comment: You will have some way to find the iframe. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

This will do it.

```
var elementDocument = $("#your-element").prop("ownerDocument");

var iframeOwner = $("iframe").filter(function() {
                      return this.contentDocument == elementDocument;
                  });
```

It ought to be quicker than the accepted answer.