# Check if two DOM elements are in the same iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is it possible to check if 2 DOM elements are in the same iframe without using an iframe id? If yes, how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12336111/492258

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak so i need to compare the ownerDocument of the two elements?

Comment: `var iframeWithNoID = document.querySelector('iframe');` or `var iwnID = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];`

Comment: I used : 
   `if(element1.ownerDocument.body == element2.ownerDocument.body)`
and looks like it works.